# Where can I get cheap light housings?

Tags: lights, parts

I have cloudy light housings from lots of miles on my car (2003 325i with glass housings). Has anyone who has ever had to replace any lighting housing, front or rear, knows how much they cost?

Where is the best place to find these kind of parts online and cheaply?

Comment: typo - I'm pretty sure that you meant "cheap" in your title question....

Comment: What's up with the downvote?  A quick comment can help us all improve our questions.

Comment: @jmort I didn't down-vote, but I also didn't up-vote or try to answer the question because relevant information was not included in the question. It's very generalized and does not include the make/model or which light, type of light. All of which influence the answer.

Comment: @Larry - Thanks for helping the OP learn how to improve question-asking ability.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cheapest option would be to polish the current light housings. You can get a kit at Wal-Mart or at any auto parts store that will allow you to turn foggy (but in otherwise good condition) headlights into much, much clearer lenses. The kits cost $15 to $20, and basically require you to use your drill, some paste, and possibly some water to wet sand the plastic lenses. You'll probably have to polish them twice with a coarse and fine grit paste, but two lenses shouldn't take more that 15 minutes. Quick, easy, and cheap!

Comment: +1 buying a new housing is generally very expensive (of course depending on the car and the age)  This solution generally helps quite a bit, especially on plastic housings.

Comment: is polishing the outside of the light housings sufficient? I have cloudy front headlight housings on my car, but I always assumed it was condensation or muck on the *inside* of the housing. Is it just the outside primarily?

Answer (score 1):

[Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/) can be a great source for parts inexpensively.  Of course, it can also be a source of questionable products and sellers, so if you are unfamiliar with it, you mean want to learn how the feedback system works and how to avoid common scams.

For example: I've had very good luck over the years, with only a few "clinkers".  I have been able to get a set of 4 OEM rims for an old car for $100, where the dealer wanted $500 each.  Of the 4, 2 were usable.  On the other hand, I only really needed one.  I've also found a variety of other parts at good prices.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check places like Rock Auto - they have the front lights for my car, for example, for about $130 each - much better than the $400 the dealer wants.